# Undefined ID/ No action Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have button X and when it's pressed than a row needs to be deleted from the database, the ID of button X is the ID that belongs to the row in the DB.
To get that button X ID I used *$(this).attr('id')*. Unfortunately it gives me undefined or nothing back in return(tested it with the console.log function).

My Jquery part:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.btn btn-xs btn-danger').click(function(){
var delete_id = $(this).attr('id');
alert(delete_id);
})
});
```

The little HTML/PHP part:

```
<form method="post">
<label id="change"><button class="btn btn-xs btn-warning" name="changing"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></button></label>
<label id="delete"><button class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" name="deleting" id="<?php echo $idError; ?>"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button></label>
</form>
```

*$idError* returns the ID from the database, so that works. The problem now is that nothing alerts(Chromes console bug doesn't give anything to). Thank you very much for helping in advance, English isn't my mother tongue so I apologizes for any grammar or misspells in my post :-)

Comment: So what id does PHP put in there exactly? i.e. What's the rendered HTML for that button?

Comment: Do I read you correctly? "the ID of button X is the ID that belongs to the row in the DB"? Do you have two ID's that are identical? That's not allowed.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I'm still expanding the code, but in order to do that I needed to fix this 'bug'. Now that it's fixed I can go on and write the PHP part of it.

Comment: Ok, I didn't see that answer. Ah, the selector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use not right selector, if target element must have many classes, you may define selector like this:

```
$('.btn.btn-xs.btn-danger').click(function(){
    var delete_id = $(this).attr('id');
    alert(delete_id);
});
```

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky, difference in selector defining.

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky this targets a button with three classes, the OPs targets a button with one class and two levels of parent

Comment: Thank you really much! It fixed it, did not think it was such a small mistake xD. I will accept your answer after 10 minutes(I need to wait from SO).